# Hiding Port number in Shiny Apps using Shiny Server

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have deployed an app using Shiny Server on AWS instance. When I run Shiny app, it launched itself at URL XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/8787/p/1234. I need to share this URL with my colleagues, but I want to hide IP+port number where shiny server is running i.e. I want to hide XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/8787, or at least one of IP/ Port should not be visible to them. Is there any way out of hiding this?
I want my colleagues to see something like XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/shiny/p/1234 (port number hided) or shiny/p/1234 (IP+port hided). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this the 127.0.0.1 address that you get by default? Because that will not be addressable from another computer. If you don't host the app on a Shiny server somewhere your colleagues will not be able to access your app anyway.

Comment: Hi
It's not 127.0.0.1. I am hosting it from shiny server. It's something like 192.168.1.34/8787/p/1234. I want it to be either 192.168.1.34/shiny/p/1234 or hide IP address. All my colleagues are in VPN, so they can easily access 192.168.1.34.

Comment: So just five out the local server DNS name. Then it will resolve to that IP number and you are good. Talk to your local Network guy if you aren't sure of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you probably already find your answer.
But a way of doing what you want is to use

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /shiny http://0.0.0.0:3838/shiny
ProxyPassReverse /shiny http://0.0.0.0:3838/shiny
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

In your httpd.conf 'your server config file this exemple is for apache'
Then you Can Access to your app in
http://ip_address/shiny/your_app_name